# Flutter : Handling Invalid value : Not in Range And Give it Initial Value in ListviewBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some problem fetching list where the number of items is not same with itemCount in ListviewBuilder .

I make Listview builder itemCount fixed **12** items because depending of total month (12).
If amount of data from **listTest** is same with ListviewBuilder (12 items), it's work perfectly like this.

### Working

[image]

But the problem is, if i deleted some item in **listTest** i got error :

### Error (I deleted 3 item)

```
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..8, inclusive: 9
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      List.[]  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:146:60)
#1      _ElectricRecordDetailScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
```

It's possible to give initial Value/Data To prevent this error , I want scenario like this.

[image]

> > **It's possible to do it ?** 
> >     Thank's.
> >
> > ### ViewScreen

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarCustom(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        centerTitle: false,
        showDrawerMenu: false,
        titleAppBar: Text('LISTRIK'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              titleHeaderRow(title: 'NO'),
              titleHeaderRow(title: 'BULAN'),
              titleHeaderRow(title: 'NILAI'),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          SizedBox(
            height: sizes.height(context) * .73,
            child: ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (ctx, index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: 12,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              cacheExtent: 200,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final indexOrder = index + 1;
                final now = DateTime.now();
                final month = DateTime(now.year, indexOrder, now.day);
                final convertMonth =
                    DateFormat.MMMM(appConfig.indonesiaLocale).format(month);
                print(convertMonth);
                listTest.sort((a, b) => a.month.compareTo(b.month));
                final result = listTest[index];
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () => showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (ctxDialog) => FormElectricTenant(),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        titleHeaderRow(title: '$indexOrder' ?? '0'),
                        titleHeaderRow(title: '$convertMonth' ?? '0'),
                        titleHeaderRow(title: '${result.value}' ?? '0'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              titleHeaderRow(title: ''),
              titleHeaderRow(title: 'Total'),
              titleHeaderRow(title: '$total'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

### Model

```
class ListTestModel {
  String id;
  int month;
  int year;
  int value;

  ListTestModel({
    this.id,
    this.month,
    this.year,
    this.value,
  });
}
```

### Dummy Data

```
List<ListTestModel> listTest = [
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 12,
    year: 2020,
    value: 2000,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 10,
    year: 2020,
    value: 1500,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 8,
    year: 2020,
    value: 3000,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 6,
    year: 2020,
    value: 3500,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 4,
    year: 2020,
    value: 5000,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 2,
    year: 2020,
    value: 4500,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 11,
    year: 2020,
    value: 2111,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 9,
    year: 2020,
    value: 5555,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 7,
    year: 2020,
    value: 333,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 5,
    year: 2020,
    value: 2222,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 3,
    year: 2020,
    value: 2222,
  ),
  ListTestModel(
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    month: 1,
    year: 2020,
    value: 2222,
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the index parameter of your builder function to check if the index exists in your list. If not, create a dummy model instead and use this.

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 12,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final listModel = listTest.firstWhere((model) => model.month == index+1, //look for valid model
                 orElse: () => ListTestModel(id:DateTime.now().toString(),month:index+1,year:2020)); //use dummy model if no valid model in your list
      return YourListTileWidget(listModel);

  },
)
```

Comment: It's working what i expected ! , i'm new to method **firstWhere** can you short explain to me what it is ? I already read documentation but it hard to understand for what this method.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. firstWhere takes a function test, wich is a function of a listelement returning a bool. This function will be executed with every element in your list until the function returns true. This element will be the result. if every element returns false, the orElse function will be executed, wich is a function that returns a listelement (can be null).